# Explain magento database structure

Tags: mysql, database, magento

I am trying to learn magento framework. But it is hard to understand the database structure. So I am looking for a document that describe what each table exactly do and explain each column in that table. I have searched on google but all I found was magento database structure without any describes (table and column) [Magento Database Diagram](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/magento_database_diagram)

ex:
the field `converted_at` in `sales_flat_quote` table. I have no idea what this field do.

What I looking for is like this topic [excellencemagentoblog.com: Magento EAV Database Structure](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-eav-database-structure/) but it is only describe  eav table

ps: so sorry because my bad english

Comment: This kind of question is a bit OT here. You might check a magento mailing list, the magento IRC channel or another magento relevant board for such questions. Beside that digging through the code indicates that `converted_at` is just an internal column that might be e.g. sometimes used by an upgrade script, but nothing that seems to be relevant for the production code.

Comment: Your second link goes to some poker website... :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Below link would solve all you queries related to Database Structure :

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-eav-database-structure/

Below 2 links would show you the Database Diagram :
http://inchoo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/MAGENTO_v1.3.2.4-Database_Diagram.pdf

Its better if you go through whole Magento Knowledge Base Documents available first and then go for understanding the Database.

EAV tables are used to give us the flexibility of adding unlimited Attributes for Products, Categories, Customers etc at any point of project even without bothering to update the database.

You need to understand Stores, Eav Attribute Set, Product Attributes, Website as all of this values are stored in Tables to differ the values.

Comment: I understand eav, product attribute but in some tables, I can't understand the field name like additional_data, converted_at,... I dont know what those field use for

Comment: Another source: [Mage Reverse Database Diagram Tool](http://www.magereverse.com/)

Comment: First link goes to a poker site.